# How do I acces the windows network?

Tags: networking

I have ubuntu 13.04 64 bit and windows 8 dual booted. I have a network that is a windows one. in recent versions of ubuntu, i wasn't able to acces it. i hoped that ubuntu 13.04 would fix that but it did not. When i go to network and click on windows network 
Unable to access location
Failed to retrieve share list from server: No such file or directory

i do not know how to make it work.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i go to network and click on windows network Unable to access location Failed to retrieve share list from server: No such file or directory

Network -> Windows network is for when you have more than 1 computer and 1 of them is a Windows system. You can connect those 2 systems and copy things over using that connection. An example where you have a network would be: Desktop with Ubuntu <-> router <-> notebook with Windows.

This has -no- relation with a dual boot system since a dual system only supports 1 OS at a time.

What you need to do is mount your Windows disc. Example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that is all I have to do?

Comment: That's what worked for me when I installed 13.04. I did nothing else. 2 things: 32 bit so not 64 bits and Windows 7 so not 8. But... both differences do not matter :)